# How do I get started reverse engineering z80 machine code?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly, decompiling, z80

I have a .z80 memory dump. How do I reverse engineer it? What do I need to know? How can I minimize manual labour?

Comment: This blog about Skoolkit seems relevant, https://mrcook.uk/reverse-engineering-zx-spectrum-games. Most importantly, it talks about .map files, which are generated at runtime by an emulator, to help identify data and code sections. This is something I did not know about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most powerful disassembler - [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro) supports z80.

Also list of disassemblers published at "[Software Development Tools for Z80 Family](http://www.z80.info/z80sdt.htm)" page

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what operating system your in, there are a lot of good tools here:

http://www.z80.info/z80sdt.htm

The first program I ever wrote was in Z80 Assembly language.